# Set multiplexer inputs to a logic 1 state

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, logic-level

How can I set, in Orcad, all the entries of multiplexer(in the picture) (except: 1, 13), to logic state '1' (for example, I understand that if I place 'ground' to some entry, then it will be equivalent to '0' logic state. That's what I want to do for '1' logic state) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://pcmunro.people.ysu.edu/Class/ECEN.Public/OrCAD.Review/DigitalOrcadSimulation.pdf

The '*PULLUP_1k*' part in '*DIG_MISC*' library, will provide 'permanent high to an input '.

Answer (score 4):

You understand that to set a logic low on an input, you need to pull the pin to GND. To set the pin to a logic high level, just do the opposite and connect the pin to VCC. You can do this, either, directly or using a pull-up resistor.

Using a resistor, would make it easier to re-work the board, if the design requirements change after the board has been manufactured.