# OrCad issue: Logic circuit simulation....ambiguous output

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, multiplexer, logic-gates, orcad

After simulating the following logic circuit(in OrCad),the resulting output -'y' is unclear. It seems to me that everything is fine, yet the result is ambiguous.

Can you, please, explain what is the problem here ? Thank you in advance.

> The Circuit:

[image]

> The Stimulus Editor:

[image]

> The Result of Simulation:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the *'VCC'* element.

---

I intended to use *'VCC'* to set input to permanent *'1'* logic state, but that's not the right way to do this.(Using 'VCC' element, the output of simulation, in my case *y*, will be two parallel red lines, one for *'1'* logic state and the other for *'0'* logic state).

As I already mentioned in [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/208904/79627), "*The 'PULLUP_1k' part in 'DIG_MISC' library, will provide 'permanent high to an input* '".

So, after I had put *'PULLUP_1k'* part instead of *'VCC'*, the simulation result was correct.